# wordpress 403, forbidden on home page

Tags: apache-2.4, wordpress

I know numerous folks have asked similar question ... wordpress is in the root folder.

I have restored a Wordpress site [mtp](https://michaeltissington.com) and get a 403 error for the home page and also wp-admin. I can access the site using `/wp-admin/index.php` and I can also access some other pages like `/meet-me/`

If I enable Wordpress `debug` and try to open `/index.php` I get a load of php depreciation warnings - but no errors.

this is my virtual host conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName michaeltissington.com
    ServerAlias www.michaeltissington.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/michaeltissington.com/html
    DirectoryIndex index.php, index.html

    <Directory "/var/www/michaeltissington.com/html">
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    LogLevel emerg
    
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=302]
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName michaeltissington.com
    ServerAlias www.michaeltissington.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/michaeltissington.com/html
    DirectoryIndex index.php, index.html

    <Directory "/var/www/michaeltissington.com/html">
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    LogLevel emerg
    
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.michaeltissington.com 
    RewriteRule ^ https://michaeltissington.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=302]

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/michaeltissington.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/michaeltissington.com/privkey.pem

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I have deleted and recreated .htaccess

```
# Browser caching
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType font/woff2 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
</IfModule>

# Block User ID Phishing Requests
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^author=([0-9]*)
    RewriteRule .* https://michaeltissington.com/? [L,R=302]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have made sure file permissions are correct by doing the following

```
find -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
find -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
```

Comment: Finally figured this out ... the line `DirectoryIndex index.php, index.html` was the cause, removing it and suddenly works. Can anyone explain why?